# MongoMapper complex query

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper

I need to achieve the following query - 
tags is an internal array in my document, and I need to query documents that
tags contains 'a' and 'b' and ('c' or 'd')

can I do that with mongomapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to do a query like this:

```
db.test.find({$and:[{tags:'a'},{tags:'b'}, {$or:[{tags:'c'}, {tags:'d'}] }]})
```

With mongomapper, try this:

```
Test.where({
  "$and" => [
    :tags => 'a',
    :tags => 'b',
    "$or" => [:tags => 'c', :tags => 'd']
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on **mpobrien**'s answer...but with correct syntax:

```
Test.where(
  :tags.all => ['a', 'b'],
  :$and => [{:tags.in => ['c', 'd']}]
)
```

Or, more directly [Mongolike](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries)...

```
Test.where(
  :tags => {
    :$all => ['a', 'b'],
    :$in  => ['b', 'c']
  }
)
```

Comment: You probably can't do `:tags.all => [...], :tags.in => [...]` because of the way [plucky](https://github.com/jnunemaker/plucky/blob/master/lib/plucky/criteria_hash.rb) resolves queries, hence the extra `:$and` clause.